# How do I handle outliers?

Tags: regression, least-squares, econometrics, regression-coefficients, outliers

I'm calculating the beta coefficients for some stocks using a single-index linear model with the OLS method. I'm computing the betas at different return intervals to assess the interval effect on the estimates. My question is, how do I handle outliers when the time horizon is 4 years? In some monthly returns (so around 50 observations), I observe significantly high kurtosis.

If you have an interesting paper about this topic, please tell me.

Comment: Chapter 16 of this book is entirely devoted to the topic. Apologies for the shameless plug. https://www.routledge.com/Understanding-Regression-Analysis-A-Conditional-Distribution-Approach/Westfall-Arias/p/book/9780367493516

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pinpointing your specific questions below:

> My question is, how do I handle outliers when the time horizon is 4 years?

Generally speaking, outright removal of outliers is almost never a good thing, so using robust methods (including quantile regression, etc.) are generally preferred for overcoming any problematic observations. I'm sure you already know this, but because you are modeling time-based data, you want to make sure that is included in some way given this is an OLS regression, but that is more a secondary point.

> If you have an interesting paper about this topic, please tell me.

The book linked [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0805822232) has an extensive section on this in Chapter 10, including detection and treatment.

Comment: Thank you so much